# Neo4j Cypher query cost more than 10s under 50 nodes plus 6000 relations situation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We did a prototype project to evaluate whether neo4j is applicable for our scenario. However, the performance is not as well as expected. So we would like to know whether it's Neo4j limitation or how should we improve it.

The scenario detail is:

1. System config: CPU Intel-i5 2.3G dual-core, Memory:16G, Neo4j version: 2.3.1
2. Only one kind of Node label and node number in the graphdb is 50. Each node has about 20 properties. Index is created on major property "nodeid";
3. Relation type is 80, but total relationship number in graphdb is about 6000 (as the test nodes only have minor difference between each other), only one property to indicate version, so no index;
4. The prototype target is: start from a specific node, to dig out all nodes with specific relationships (about 50) as a net.

The Cypher query through browser costs more than 10 seconds. As there is only 50 nodes, is this as expected? Below is the cypher query command we used:

```
MATCH
  (startnode:MYNode {nodeid:"123456"})-[r1:REL1|:REL2......|:REL50 {version:1}]-
  (target1:MYNode)-[r2:REL1|:REL2......|:REL50 {version:1}]-
  (target2:MYNode)-[r3:REL1|:REL2......|:REL50 {version:1}]-(target3:MYNode)
WHERE target1.timestamp > 1449417600 AND  target2.timestamp > 1449417600 AND target3.timestamp > 1449417600 
RETURN
  DISTINCT target2.nodeid as l_id,
  target2.timestamp as l_ts,
  type(r3) as r_type,
  target3.nodeid as r_id,
  target3.timestamp as r_ts 
LIMIT 5000;
```

Below is profile output:

```
Compiler CYPHER 2.3

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator        | Estimated Rows | Rows  | DB Hits | Identifiers                                 | Other
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-----------------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults |             93 |  5000 |       0 | l_appts, l_id, r_appts, r_id, r_type        | l_id, l_appts, r_type, r_id, r_appts
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Limit          |             93 |  5000 |       0 | l_appts, l_id, r_appts, r_id, r_type        | Literal(5000)
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Distinct       |             93 |  5000 |  627064 | l_appts, l_id, r_appts, r_id, r_type        | r_id, l_appts, r_appts, l_id, r_type
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |             98 | 78383 |  313881 | r1, r2, r3, seed, target1, target2, target3 | Ands(r3.version == {  AUTOINT3}, NOT(r2 == r3), NOT(r1 == r3), AndedPropertyComparablePredicates(    target3,target3.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP,target3.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP < {  AUTOINT9}, target3.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP > {  AUTOINT8}), target3:APPNode)
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |            977 | 78732 |   96630 | r1, r2, r3, seed, target1, target2, target3 | (target2)-[r3:ID__ID|:ID__ID_C1|:ID__ID_C2|:ID_C1__ID_C1|:ID_C1__ID_C2|:ID_C1__ID|:ID_C2__ID_C1|:ID_C2__    ID_C2|:ID_C2__ID|:CELLPHONE__CELLPHONE|:CELLPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:CELLPHONE__EMPPHONE|:CELLPHONE__C1PHONE|:CELLPHONE__C2PHONE|:HOMEPHONE__CELLPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__EMPPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__C1PHON    E|:HOMEPHONE__C2PHONE|:EMPPHONE__CELLPHONE|:EMPPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:EMPPHONE__EMPPHONE|:EMPPHONE__C1PHONE|:EMPPHONE__C2PHONE|:C1PHONE__CELLPHONE|:C1PHONE__HOMEPHONE|:C1PHONE__EMPPHONE|:C1PHONE__C1PHONE|:C1PHO    NE__C2PHONE|:C2PHONE__CELLPHONE|:C2PHONE__HOMEPHONE|:C2PHONE__EMPPHONE|:C2PHONE__C1PHONE|:C2PHONE__C2PHONE|:EMAIL__EMAIL|:CARLICENSE__CARLICENSE|:EMPNAME__EMPNAME|:IPADDR__IPADDR|:MACADDR__MACADDR|:WIFIMAC    __WIFIMAC|:HOMEADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:HOMEADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__C1ADDR__P
0|:HOMEADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:HOMEADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__EMPADDR__P0]-(target3) |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |             21 |   314 |    1260 | r1, r2, seed, target1, target2              | Ands(AndedPropertyComparablePredicates(target2,target2.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP,target2.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP <     {  AUTOINT7}, target2.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP > {  AUTOINT6}), target2:APPNode, r2.version == {  AUTOINT2}, NOT(r1 == r2))
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |            212 |   315 |     429 | r1, r2, seed, target1, target2              | (target1)-[r2:ID__ID|:ID__ID_C1|:ID__ID_C2|:ID_C1__ID_C1|:ID_C1__ID_C2|:ID_C1__ID|:ID_C2__ID_C1|:ID_C2__    ID_C2|:ID_C2__ID|:CELLPHONE__CELLPHONE|:CELLPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:CELLPHONE__EMPPHONE|:CELLPHONE__C1PHONE|:CELLPHONE__C2PHONE|:HOMEPHONE__CELLPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__EMPPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__C1PHON    E|:HOMEPHONE__C2PHONE|:EMPPHONE__CELLPHONE|:EMPPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:EMPPHONE__EMPPHONE|:EMPPHONE__C1PHONE|:EMPPHONE__C2PHONE|:C1PHONE__CELLPHONE|:C1PHONE__HOMEPHONE|:C1PHONE__EMPPHONE|:C1PHONE__C1PHONE|:C1PHO    NE__C2PHONE|:C2PHONE__CELLPHONE|:C2PHONE__HOMEPHONE|:C2PHONE__EMPPHONE|:C2PHONE__C1PHONE|:C2PHONE__C2PHONE|:EMAIL__EMAIL|:CARLICENSE__CARLICENSE|:EMPNAME__EMPNAME|:IPADDR__IPADDR|:MACADDR__MACADDR|:WIFIMAC    __WIFIMAC|:HOMEADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:HOMEADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__C1ADDR__P
0|:HOMEADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:HOMEADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__EMPADDR__P0]-(target2) |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |              5 |     2 |       8 | r1, seed, target1                           | Ands(r1.version == {  AUTOINT1}, target1:APPNode, AndedPropertyComparablePredicates(target1,target1.    STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP,target1.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP > {  AUTOINT4}, target1.STAN_APP_TIMESTAMP < {  AUTOINT5}))
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |             46 |     2 |      59 | r1, seed, target1                           | (seed)-[r1:ID__ID|:ID__ID_C1|:ID__ID_C2|:ID_C1__ID_C1|:ID_C1__ID_C2|:ID_C1__ID|:ID_C2__ID_C1|:ID_C2__ID_    C2|:ID_C2__ID|:CELLPHONE__CELLPHONE|:CELLPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:CELLPHONE__EMPPHONE|:CELLPHONE__C1PHONE|:CELLPHONE__C2PHONE|:HOMEPHONE__CELLPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__EMPPHONE|:HOMEPHONE__C1PHONE|:    HOMEPHONE__C2PHONE|:EMPPHONE__CELLPHONE|:EMPPHONE__HOMEPHONE|:EMPPHONE__EMPPHONE|:EMPPHONE__C1PHONE|:EMPPHONE__C2PHONE|:C1PHONE__CELLPHONE|:C1PHONE__HOMEPHONE|:C1PHONE__EMPPHONE|:C1PHONE__C1PHONE|:C1PHONE_    _C2PHONE|:C2PHONE__CELLPHONE|:C2PHONE__HOMEPHONE|:C2PHONE__EMPPHONE|:C2PHONE__C1PHONE|:C2PHONE__C2PHONE|:EMAIL__EMAIL|:CARLICENSE__CARLICENSE|:EMPNAME__EMPNAME|:IPADDR__IPADDR|:MACADDR__MACADDR|:WIFIMAC__W    IFIMAC|:HOMEADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:HOMEADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:
HOMEADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:HOMEADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__C1ADDR__P0|:EMPADDR__C2ADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C1ADDR__EMPADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__HOMEADDR__P0|:C2ADDR__EMPADDR__P0]-(target1)    |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek  |              1 |     1 |       2 | seed                                        | :APPNode(APP_ID)
                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-----------------+----------------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 1039333
```

Comment: Can you share a PROFILE output and the database (zipped)?

Comment: Hi Michael, I've added the profile output in my original questions. @MichaelHunger

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your domain? It is unusual to match against such a high number of rel-types at once. Usually you'd just leave them off and post-filter if needed.

Comment: Have you tried `path=(startnode:MYNode {nodeid:"123456"})-[rels:REL1|:REL2......|:REL50*2..2 {version:1}]-
  (target1:MYNode)`?  It's more compact, you can pull out the nodes from the path with `nodes(path)`, get the rels with the `rels` variable, and you can use `EXTRACT` / `UNWIND` to work with the collections

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate your database and statement. The problem is that you span up a huge lattice, and you're post-filtering with distinct.

If you reduce the WIP in between (as you are interested in the distinct results anyway) using WITH DISTINCT, then it completes in a few ms for me.

```
MATCH (startnode:MYNode {nodeid:1})
-[r1:REL1|:REL2|:REL3|:REL4|:REL5|:REL6|:REL7|:REL8|:REL9|:REL10|:REL11|:REL12|:REL13|:REL14|:REL15|:REL16|:REL17|:REL18|:REL19|:REL20|:REL21|:REL22|:REL23|:REL24|:REL25|:REL26|:REL27|:REL28|:REL29|:REL30|:REL31|:REL32|:REL33|:REL34|:REL35|:REL36|:REL37|:REL38|:REL39|:REL40|:REL41|:REL42|:REL43|:REL44|:REL45|:REL46|:REL47|:REL48|:REL49|:REL50 {version:1}]-(target1:MYNode)
WHERE target1.timestamp > 1449417600 WITH distinct target1

MATCH (target1)-[r2:REL1|:REL2|:REL3|:REL4|:REL5|:REL6|:REL7|:REL8|:REL9|:REL10|:REL11|:REL12|:REL13|:REL14|:REL15|:REL16|:REL17|:REL18|:REL19|:REL20|:REL21|:REL22|:REL23|:REL24|:REL25|:REL26|:REL27|:REL28|:REL29|:REL30|:REL31|:REL32|:REL33|:REL34|:REL35|:REL36|:REL37|:REL38|:REL39|:REL40|:REL41|:REL42|:REL43|:REL44|:REL45|:REL46|:REL47|:REL48|:REL49|:REL50 {version:1}]-(target2:MYNode)
WHERE  target2.timestamp > 1449417600 WITH distinct target2

MATCH (target2)-[r3:REL1|:REL2|:REL3|:REL4|:REL5|:REL6|:REL7|:REL8|:REL9|:REL10|:REL11|:REL12|:REL13|:REL14|:REL15|:REL16|:REL17|:REL18|:REL19|:REL20|:REL21|:REL22|:REL23|:REL24|:REL25|:REL26|:REL27|:REL28|:REL29|:REL30|:REL31|:REL32|:REL33|:REL34|:REL35|:REL36|:REL37|:REL38|:REL39|:REL40|:REL41|:REL42|:REL43|:REL44|:REL45|:REL46|:REL47|:REL48|:REL49|:REL50 {version:1}]-(target3:MYNode) 
WHERE  target3.timestamp > 1449417600 
RETURN target2.nodeid as l_id, target2.timestamp as l_ts, type(r3) as r_type, target3.nodeid as r_id, target3.timestamp as r_ts 
LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: Brilliant, Michael! I modified my cypher query statement like your post, it improved a lot. Now it cost 1.8s now, but still can't achieve to ms level. Could you please help to look at my database? I attached the dropbox link here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymi52hlywpqegg3/graph_copy.db.zip?dl=0).

Comment: also attached my cypher query statement which cost 1.8s  in https://www.dropbox.com/s/usdjgo8gp519a41/cyper_query.txt?dl=0 @Michael Hunger